# cannot use cin twice, also cin.clear and cin.ignore don't work

Tags: c++, eof, cin

I'm new to C++ programming, and I've come upon a roadblock. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int sum = 0, a;
    cout << "enter first set of numbers:";
    while(cin >> a) sum += a;
    cout << "first sum = " << sum;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    sum = 0;
    cout << "enter second set of numbers:";
    while(cin >> a) sum += a;
    cout << "second sum = " << sum;
}
```

I'm trying to sum two sets of numbers that I input at the command line. The problem is that when I hit ctrl-d to terminate my first set of numbers, it skips the second set of cin's. Most of the pages I find elsewhere on the internet tell me to use cin.clear and cin.ignore. I've tried that and it still doesn't work. This page [question concerning cin.clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130925/question-concerning-cin-clear) even seems to have the same problems. However, the fixes they suggest don't work for me.

Does this code above work for anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

When you use Ctrl-D you terminate the input stream: there is no further character coming from `std::cin`. Even clearing the stream doesn't help: you have told the stream it is at its end. You can't reopen it. However, `clear()`ing the stream and using `ignore()` is the solution to your problem!

You need a different indicator that one set of values is done. The easiest is to use a non-digit character or string: trying to read something which isn't an `int` will cause the stream to go into failure mode [without closing the stream]. That is, you read until the conversion fails, `clear()` the stream, and `ignore()` everything up to the end of the line.

Your code should already do that: instead of using Ctrl-D just enter, e.g., `x`.

Comment: Okay, terminating with a character instead of ctrl-d works; thanks a lot. I'm just wondering, why does chapter 4 of the book Accelerated C++ seem to suggest that not only will ctrl-d work fine for multiple "blocks" of cin's, but that I only need cin.clear, rather than both cin.ignore?

Comment: @user2990344: I'd think you need to get rid of the offending character, i.e., you'd need `std::cin.ignore()`. How they got the idea that Ctrl-D should work, I don't know. Seems odd to me as Andrew certainly knows better.

Comment: @xdavidliu This behavior is different on macOS vs. Linux. There's a maddening amount of misinformation about it on stackoverflow, but from what I can tell (though I'm not an expert): the example would have worked fine on Linux, but on macOS you also need to reopen `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

//Use stringstream ^^ for multiple user input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    string mystr;
    float price = 0;
    int quantity = 0;

    cout << "Enter price: ";
    getline (cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> price;
    cout << "Enter quantity:";
    getline (cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> quantity;
    cout << "Total price: " << price*quantity << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ctrl-D, you just need to have your loop in another thread. So Ctrl-D, kills the thread, then returns to your main function, then you can start another thread.
It'd not the best solution, but it can work, http://codebase.eu/tutorial/posix-threads-c/