# `cin.clear()` leaves the input stream in failure state

Tags: c++, istream

I am reading the book 'Accelerated C++', and I am unable to reproduce the results for their read homework problem even after exactly copying their code on my machine. The basic problem is about using cin.clear() to change the failure state of the inpute stream after the use of EOF to indicate that all the grades have been entered. Authors suggest Ctrl+D on linux systems for EOF. I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732434/cin-clear-leave-eof-in-stream) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130925/question-concerning-cin-clear) but they couldn't solve my problem.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name, city;
    vector<double> homework;
    cout << "Enter your name : " ;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " + name + "!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter your grades" << endl;
    if (cin)
    {
        homework.clear();
        double x;
        while (cin >> x)
        {
            homework.push_back(x);
        }
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter your city : " ;
    cin >> city ; 
    cout << "You live in " + city << endl;; 
    return 0;
}
```

After entering all the homework, I hit Ctrl+D and then I expect that I would now be given chance to enter city name. But the program just ends after printing the two strings at the end of my code. What is wrong with my understanding of `cin.clear()`? I would also like to point out that using `cin.ignore()` after `cin.clear()` doesn't help either.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Could you please tell me one? I badly need to learn C++ fast.

Comment: Do you need to pass some exam or learn c++? This exercise (or example) is contrived, you don't have to use EOF as end of grades, if it causes trouble. Use whatever does work, keep progressing.

Comment: @ddbug Not exam. I need to rewrite a large number of fortran legacy codes in C++ and I have something like 1 year of time with me.

Comment: @ddbug What is the exact problem with the code though, and what is the solution? Could you also recommend me a good resource?

Comment: Sorry, don't know any book that helps instantly (( The problem IMHO is that EOF (ctrl/D in Linux) renders `cin` unusable TL;DR.So avoid it. For example, instruct the user to input 0 or negative number as end of grades. Then just keep reading further data. First make it work, only then make cosmetic improvements.

Comment: @ddbug Thanks so much. I would be grateful if you could tell me an up to date and a good resource to learn C++

Comment: @Peaceful If you want to learn how to write good, modern `C++` use PluralSight and take any of the courses by Kate Gregory

Answer (score 1):

On fail you need to clear the flags and ignore ***all*** the bad input.

Include `#include <limits>` for `std::numeric_limits`.

```
    if ( std::cin.fail( ) )
    {
        std::cin.clear( );
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max( ), '\n');
    }
```

If you want a way to exit the loop use a value that you can test for (like -1). When you receive that value, exit the loop.

```
double value{ 0 };
while( std::cin >> value && value != -1 )
    homework.push_back( value );

if ( std::cin.fail( ) )
{
    std::cin.clear( );
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max( ), '\n');
}
```

Edit:

I didn't see that you were trying to end the `stream` with `EOF`.
Read this answer to figure out how to accomplish this.

[How to resume input stream after stopped by EOF in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815349/how-to-resume-input-stream-after-stopped-by-eof-in-c)

Comment: This throws error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’; I am compiling with g++ by the way.

Comment: Added the `header` you need in the answer

Comment: Thanks. But with the cin.ignore() solution (that doesn't use -1), the program still does what it was doing earlier: after Ctrl+D, it just ends without taking input for the city name.

Comment: @Peaceful Updated answer